# git push heroku master with node.js deploy hanging

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, webpack, bundle

my app runs locally but when trying to deploy to heroku, it just hangs. when i go to the website, it shows one public file but nothing else. it has this error message. i've been trying to figure this out for days to no avail. i'd be so grateful if anyone has any insight please!

```
https://analogy-alley.herokuapp.com/bundle.js Failed to load  

resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

my terminal shows this when the deploy hangs:

```
Counting objects: 80, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (75/75), done.
Writing objects: 100% (80/80), 8.04 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 80 (delta 48), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  6.3.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   3.10.3
remote:        
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.3.1...
remote:        npm 3.10.3 already installed with node
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        analogy-alley@1.0.0 /tmp/build_7618a5799d312965a2e80f859861d507
remote:        └─┬ latest-version@2.0.0
remote:        └─┬ package-json@2.4.0
remote:        ├─┬ got@5.7.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ create-error-class@3.0.2
remote:        │ │ └── capture-stack-trace@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── duplexer2@0.1.4
remote:        │ ├── is-redirect@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── is-retry-allowed@1.1.0
remote:        │ ├── lowercase-keys@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── node-status-codes@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ parse-json@2.2.0
remote:        │ │ └─┬ error-ex@1.3.0
remote:        │ │   └── is-arrayish@0.2.1
remote:        │ ├── read-all-stream@3.1.0
remote:        │ ├── timed-out@3.1.3
remote:        │ ├── unzip-response@1.0.2
remote:        │ └─┬ url-parse-lax@1.0.0
remote:        │   └── prepend-http@1.0.4
remote:        ├─┬ registry-auth-token@3.1.0
remote:        │ └─┬ rc@1.1.6
remote:        │   ├── deep-extend@0.4.1
remote:        │   ├── ini@1.3.4
remote:        │   ├── minimist@1.2.0
remote:        │   └── strip-json-comments@1.0.4
remote:        ├── registry-url@3.1.0
remote:        └── semver@5.3.0
remote:        
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > analogy-alley@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_7618a5799d312965a2e80f859861d507
remote:        > webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js
remote:        
remote:        Hash: c32f71d9e77f2e675558
remote:        Version: webpack 1.14.0
remote:        Time: 11716ms
remote:        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
remote:        ./public/bundle.js   238 kB       0  [emitted]  main
remote:        ./public/bundle.js.map  1.92 MB       0  [emitted]  main
remote:        + 206 hidden modules
remote:        
remote:        WARNING in ./public/bundle.js from UglifyJs
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponentTree.js:103,0]
remote:        Dropping unused variable analogy [./browser/react/container/AnalogyBox.js:105,9]
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/ReactNodeTypes.js:35,0]
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js:77,0]
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js:99,0]
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:144,0]
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:976,0]
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:263,0]
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:283,0]
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:53,0]
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:55,0]
remote:        Condition always true [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:144,0]
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "analogy-alley",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.3.1", 
    "npm": "3.10.3"
  },
  "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL"
  },
  "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack -w & nodemon --watch server -e js,html index.js",
    "build": "check-node-version --node '>= 6.7.0' && webpack",
    "build-watch": "check-node-version --node '>= 6.7.0' && webpack -w",
    "heroku-postbuild": "webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jsharonk/analogy-alley.git"
  },
  "author": "jsk",
  "dependencies": {
    "ajax": "0.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "latest-version": "^2.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "pg": "^6.1.2",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "sequelize": "^3.29.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.18.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue (hanging on the webpack step) and solved it removing the `watch: true` property from the webpack config file.